# Matlab: create an array list

Tags: arrays, matlab, list

I have a series of results at the end a while loop. These results are not saved in an array but they are shown for esch loop.
I want to copy all these results, that are created for each loop, in an array, in a list.
For example

```
while(condition)
    do something
    if(condition)
    a=b;
    else a=c
    end
end
```

I want all b in a list. How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please add some lines of your code? It would make easier answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a loop which output variables `a,b,c`, you can "append" these variables at the end of an array `A` by adding at the end of the loop
`A(end+1,:) = [a,b,c];`

`A(end+1,:)` created a new row to which `[a,b,c]` are then assigned.

In your case you can create an empty list `all_b=[]` before the `while` loop.
Then you can add within the loop `all_b(end+1) = b`, which will save the current b in an all_b list.